# How to select several elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

How can I hide from the third paragraph to the last one?
So far I managed to hide only the first one:

```
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<p>D</p>
<p>E</p>

<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[2].style.display="none";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thoughts would be to use CSS directly:

```
p:nth-child(n + 3) {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KGPZ5/).

Or using plain JavaScript:

```
var pElems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 2, len = pElems.length; i < len; i++) {
    pElems[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KGPZ5/1/).

Of course, just because it's possible (and yes, you *can* do this, but that doesn't mean you *should*), we could also extend the `Array` prototype, and make use of `slice`, and `call`:

```
Array.prototype.css = function (prop,val) {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0, len = self.length; i < len; i++) {
        self[i].style[prop] = val;
    }
    return self;
};
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), 2).css('display','none');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KGPZ5/2/).

---

**Edited** in response to question, left in the comments (below), by the OP:

> what would be the shortest [JavaScript] to hide just the last one `<p>`?

I don't often enter into 'shortest' competitions (redolent of code golf, though the techniques are often impressive); however the *simplest* approach is as-written in the comment:

```
var pArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
pArray[pArray.length-1].style.display="none";
```

I originally suggested using `pop()` (forgetting that a `NodeList` doesn't have a `pop()` method) So, to further the above prototype-extending approach (and avoiding re-creating `pop()`, mainly because `slice()` seemed to be far more useful in later situations:

```
Array.prototype.css = function (prop,val) {
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 0, len = self.length; i < len; i++) {
        self[i].style[prop] = val;
    }
    return self;
};

NodeList.prototype.slice = function (a,b) {
    return [].slice.call(this, a, b);
}
var pArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

pArray.slice(-1).css('display','none');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GFRyL/3/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: sorry, but what would be the shortest javascript to hide just the last one <p>?

Comment: It seems I found: `var pArray = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

pArray[pArray.length-1].style.display="none";`

Comment: sorry, but seems Your example doesn't work in my case: [JS Fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Roberts002/ye8NN/7/)

Comment: Fair enough, when I get a chance, after dinner, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks David! Here is clean example: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Roberts002/GFRyL/)

Comment: Sorry for the time it took to compose my reply. I think the edits should answer your (new) question as well?

Comment: Yes, it does - thanks David! I'll stick to short version [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Roberts002/ye8NN/11/)

Answer (score 3):

As it's tagged with jQuery:

```
$('p:gt(1)').hide();
```

> :gt = Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set (zero based)